# maven-invoker doesn't call install on dependency

Tags: maven, build, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

i have a problem in my maven build process. there is a pom file which uses the maven-invoker-plugin to execute different tasks:

```
<execution>
<id>createWebstartApps</id>

<phase>process-resources</phase>
<goals>
<goal>run</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
<projectsDirectory>.</projectsDirectory>
<streamLogs>true</streamLogs>
<pomIncludes>
    <pomInclude>pom1.xml</pomInclude>
</pomIncludes>
....
```

but when i use the maven release plugin "mvn release:prepare" the install goal will not be executed on the child pom dependencies. For example the pom1.xml has the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.qnamic.dis</groupId>
<artifactId>DisAdminToolWithPlugins</artifactId>
<version>${project.parent.version}</version>
<type>pom</type>
<scope>runtime</scope>
.....
```

But this dependency (in this case the pom file) will not be installed in my local maven repo and therefore not be found:

```
  [INFO] [INFO] Building: pomWebstartDisAdminTool.xml
[INFO] [INFO] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] [INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] [INFO] Building RailOpt DIS Admin Tool 4.9.12
[INFO] [INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] [WARNING] The POM for com.qnamic.dis:DisAdminToolWithPlugins:pom:4.9.12 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] [INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] [INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] [INFO] Total time: 0.203s
[INFO] [INFO] [INFO] Finished at: Tue Feb 05 13:00:04 CET 2013
[INFO] [INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[INFO] [INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project DisAdminToolWebstart: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.qnamic.dis:DisAdminToolWebstart:pom:4.9.12: Failure to find com.qnamic.dis:DisAdminToolWithPlugins:pom:4.9.12 in http://maven.ad.bls.ch/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of bls-public has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

any ideas?

regards

Comment: Why are you using to use maven-invoker to do other **task** which usually don't exist in Maven. What are you trying to achieve? You should think about configuration of extraArtifacts of the maven-inovker-plugin.

Comment: hi! i can't answer your question because this was existing (old) code and i'm just trying to make it build again. i also think there should be a better way to do this..but i'm no maven expert :-/ i'm also open to new ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding install before run. Eg.

```
<execution>
  <id>createWebstartApps</id>
  <phase>process-resources</phase>
  <goals>
    <goal>install</goal>
    <goal>run</goal>
  </goals>
...
```

For more information: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/install-mojo.html & http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/usage.html

HTH,
Jamie

Comment: i tried that already yesterday. today again and now it works! maybe i had something else changed in the configruation too...thanks!

Comment: Eclipse now tells me the following: Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-invoker-plugin:1.6:install (execution: createWebstartApps, phase: process-resources). Maven works, but Eclipse has somehow a problem with this configuration

Comment: Doesn't sound entirely logical to me. Eclipse does nothing much more than just invoke Maven. Could it be that the Versions invoked by Eclipse & from the command line aren't the same?

Answer (score 1):

Add the file invoker.properties next to your pom.xml
and put your goals into it, like:

```
invoker.goals = clean install
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dependency that is failing to resolve is an internal dependency i.e. another module in your project then you may be able to resolve this by adding the [`<extraArtifacts>`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/install-mojo.html#extraArtifacts) configuration to the invoker plugin configuration in your `pom.xml`.

For example here's one from one of my open source projects:

```xml
<extraArtifacts>
  <extraArtifact>com.github.rvesse:airline:${airline.version}:jar:tests</extraArtifact>
  <extraArtifact>com.github.rvesse:airline-examples:${airline.version}:jar</extraArtifact>
</extraArtifacts>
```

Where `airline.version` happens to be a property I'm setting based on `project.version`

This tells the invoker plugin to `install` these dependencies into the local integration test repository ensuring they are available to your integration tests.